# Can't install Ubuntu 12.10 - NVIDIA display through HDMI - Invalid Format (LG TV)

Tags: installation, nvidia, hdmi

First, I am new to Linux in general so my knowledge is little. I am having a problem installing Ubuntu 12.10 on my desktop. I can’t install or run the live cd of Ubuntu, on my display it appear invalid format. I will like to know if there is way for installing Ubuntu. I read some forums and it appears that the problem is my NVIDIA Video Card through the HDMI (Well that’s what I think).

I have the following hardware specs:
Motherboard: Asus Maximus V Extreme 
Video Card: NVIDIA GTX680
RAM: Corsair 32 GB
Hard Drive: 500 GB
Display: LG TV – Through HDMI 1080p (I don’t have a different type of connector)

Attempts:

1.I downloaded the .iso file and burn it on a CD/DVD disk. After that in the menu I tried both options, to install Ubuntu and Try Ubuntu and install.

Results: By either way I could not install Ubuntu. It only shows a black screen with my TV displaying the invalid format message.

2.I downloaded yet again in other PC the .iso file and now installed it on a USB as the guide provided by Ubuntu shows. After that in the menu I tried both options, to install Ubuntu and Try Ubuntu and install.

Results: By either way I could not install Ubuntu. It only shows a black screen with my TV displaying the invalid format message.

I will appreciate any guidance on this matter. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to say some scary words and they're probably not going to make complete sense but here's the situation.

- There is a freely distributable, open source driver for Nvidia cards called Nouveau.
- If you have a Nvidia card and no other driver, Nouveau will try to load.
- The LiveCD only ships with free software. Nouveau is loaded and this works for some people.
- For modern hardware (I have your issue with a GTX580) things fail hard.

All you need to do is pass `nomodeset` to the kernel at the boot screen.

Probably lost you but when you boot up you're presented with a language choice and then a list of things to do. Under that list, there's another list of options. I think it's currently under F6 but anyway, enable nomodeset (or add it manually to the boot line).

That should get you into the live CD. At first *real* boot you may run into exactly the same issue. The closed source driver still won't be installed. The prodecure is slightly different this time but just use the grub menus to edit and then add `nomodeset` to the command line. As soon as you're in, install `nvidia-current` and all your problems should be solved.

There's [more on using nomodeset here on UbuntuForums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132).

Comment: Thank you for your reply Oli, I will read the link you gave me and try your suggestion. I will let you know how it turned out. Thanks in advance.